# Method to register generic configuration on IServiceCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, configuration

We need to create a generic method to get any settings for services. We have an configuration class for each 'Service', but all have the same 'key' in the file `appsettings.json.`

A common example:

```
public abstract class BaseProgram
{

   protected IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
   ...

   protected internal void ConfigureServices()
   {
      serviceCollection.Configure<MyConfiguration1>(configuration.GetSection("IndividualConfiguration"));
      serviceCollection.Configure<MyConfiguration2>(configuration.GetSection("IndividualConfiguration"));
      serviceCollection.Configure<MyConfiguration3>(configuration.GetSection("IndividualConfiguration"));
   }
```

We would like to create something more generic, something like this:

```
public T ServiceParameters<T>()
{
    return serviceCollection.Configure<T>(configuration.GetSection("IndividualConfiguration"));
}
```

Sample call:

```
var call1 = whatever.ServiceParameters<MyConfiguration1>();
...
var call2 = whatever.ServiceParameters<MyConfiguration2>();
```

However, it is not possible with the current implementation `TOptions`:

> Registers a configuration instance which TOptions will bind against.
>
> Type Parameters:
>   TOptions: The type of options being configured.

Problem:

> The type "T" must be a reference type to be used as a "TOptions" parameter in the generic type or method 
>   `OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.Configure <TOptions>(IServiceCollection, IConfiguration)`.

This is only possible if we extend the class? Or we writing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The only constraint is that [TOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsconfigurationservicecollectionextensions.configure?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions_Configure__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_) must be a class

Declare your method like this:

```
public IServiceCollection ServiceParameters<T>() where T : class
```

If not the compiler assumes that you want to pass anything as a type parameter including structs and the `Configure` method cannot accept that.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto is the answer not helpful? does it deserve a downvote? You have almost 17k, you should know better that votes are not for "dislike".

Comment: No, it is not. From [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates): "The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place." That's why we search for duplicates before answering